# Adding to List<t> becomes very slow over time

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm parsing an html table that has about 1000 rows. I'm adding ~10 char string from one `<td>` in each row to a `list<string>` object. It's very quick for the first 200 or so loops but then becomes slower and slower over time.

This is the code i'm using:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        int maxRows = numRows;


        for (int i = 1; i < maxRows; i++)
        { 
            TableRow newTable = myTable.TableRows[i];
            string coll = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}",newTable.TableCells[0].Text,newTable.TableCells[1].Text,newTable.TableCells[2].Text,newTable.TableCells[3].Text,newTable.TableCells[4].Text);
            myList.Add(coll);
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
```

Should I use an array instead?

**Edit:** I threw the above code in a new method that gets run on a new `Thread` and then updated my label control with this code:

```
label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    label1.Text = i.ToString();
                });
```

Program runs at a consistent speed and doesn't block the UI.

Comment: What's your definition of slow? There's nothing in the code you posted that indicates why it should slow down.

Comment: Do you really mean to set the Text property of your label1 on each iteration of your for loop?

Comment: 1000 items isn't all that many. I never use arrays. I doubt you'll notice a difference

Comment: @Gabe, it takes 3 seconds to go from 1-200. 200-400 takes about a minute. From 1 -100 takes 5 min. I don't understand why it is starting out very fast and going to a crawl shortly after.

Comment: Not sure, but this might be an example of stale references causing [midlife crisis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/04/41281.aspx). @Jay: I'm pretty sure that's the likely cause.

Comment: @Jay Riggs, It's my lazy progress bar. It takes forever with and without it so it's nice to see the progress.

Comment: @Nick You ought to check into using a BackgroundWorker with a real ProgressBar.

Comment: You should also use a profiler if you can. Maybe the addition operation is not the slowest part of the loop iteration

Comment: @Jay I bet you are firing off too many updates to the progress bar and thats why it bogs down. I had a similar issue with a progress bar and a BackGroundWorker. Try commenting that out and see what happens.

Comment: Maybe the access to `TableRows[i]` is somehow O(n) and is slow. It would explain why it gets slower with `i` growing.

Comment: If you remove the `Add` function call, you will no doubt see that it still takes a long time. My guess is that it's the `myTable.TableRows[i]` dereference that takes longer as `i` increases.

Comment: Also, seeing as you're working with HTML here, I suspect that `Text` property is doing some nasty work like removing tags and stuff. This is never snappy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you roughly know the range (number of items) in your collection it is better to use an array.

> Reason : Every time you add an element to the List if the list is full it allocates new block of memory to hold the double the current space and copies everything there and then keeps appending the additional entries till it becomes full, and one more allocation copy cycle.

Following is how it works AFAIK, start with 16 elements by default,
when you add 17th element to the list it allocates 32 elemnts and copies 16 there then continues for 17 to 32. and repeats this process, so it is slower but offer flexibility of not having to determine the length beforehand. This might be the reason you're seeing the drag.

Thanks @Dyppl 
`var list = new List<int>(1000);` This is one elegant option too, as @Dyppl suggested it is best of both the worlds.

Comment: So it only grows when it needs to. If you roughly know the range (number of items), just create a List like that: `var list = new List<int>(1000);` and it will contain an array of corresponding size within.

Comment: Except for the fact that memory allocations are incredibly fast. Presizing the List<> can help, but this is a list of 1000 string references or so. The Arrays versus List<> tends argument to be micro-optimization theatre as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Ritch Melton: allocations are fast, copying is no faster than O(n), but still you have a point

Comment: I think, List<T> starts at 4 elements.

Comment: I doubt the list is the reason. 1000 list entries will cost 2048 entries as most. Better see, if the strings grow too large!

Comment: @Nick, try using an array, and if the difference is not much, then probably something to do with the string you are creating in each iteration, I guess. And List is a wrong place to optimize then.

Answer (score 9):

I tested adding strings to a list, and benchmarked it with a `LIST_SIZE` of *1000000* (one million) items and a `LIST_SIZE` of *100000* (one hundred thousands) items. This way we can compare how it scales.

I ran each test 5 times and averaged the running times.

---

```
var l = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; ++i) {
    l.Add("i = " + i.ToString());
}
```

`LIST_SIZE` of `1000000` takes **1519 ms**

`LIST_SIZE` of `100000` takes **96 ms**

---

```
var l = new List<string>(LIST_SIZE);
for (var i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; ++i) {
    l.Add("i = " + i.ToString());
}
```

`LIST_SIZE` of `1000000` takes **1386 ms**

`LIST_SIZE` of `100000` takes **65 ms**

---

```
var l = new string[LIST_SIZE];
for (var i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; ++i) {
    l[i] = "i = " + i.ToString();
}
```

`LIST_SIZE` of `1000000` takes **1510 ms**

`LIST_SIZE` of `100000` takes **66 ms**

So, we can notice 2 things:

- it really takes more time to add each items the longer the list gets larger
- the difference shouldn't be noticeable in a 1000 items list

I would conclude then that the bottleneck is in one of the other methods you call.

Comment: I just realized a flaw in my test, it overestimates the time for larger lists because the bigger the number `i` get, it costs more to convert to string. But, I just tested it with equal sized strings and it still holds that it takes more time to add each item as the list grows (even using arrays), just the difference is not that big.

Comment: This has been done many times. Here's a decent article with a graph: http://allantech.blogspot.com/2007/03/performance-arraylist-vs-list.html

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the List with the capacity you expect it to consume:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>(maxRows);
```

Sidenote: If you generate *'very'* large lists, the internally increasing storage arrays over time sum up to twice the storage you really need. But if for 1000 entries you already slow down, I suggest investigating the true reason for it with a profiler. May the strings grow to large ?

Comment: ok, should have read the comments first. This was suggested in the comments to the other answer as well. sorry